# ASP.NET Membership Registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

I am trying to implement the asp.net membership registration but getting quite tired of it not working. Is there any really simple tutorials for this.

Is it easier just to implement my OWN registration tables for usernames and passwords or is it a standard to use Microsoft's membership provider. I know it's probably encrypts and salts the passwords which is already preset but it seems like too much work just to get this working.

I have implemented authentication system previously without this but it's seems Microsoft really wants you to use this.

Comment: I got it to work btw, but I am still confused about all the possibilities and uses of this system

Comment: If you are use Entity Framework with MVC, then you feel, it's too much easiest method for authentication.

Comment: What are you trying to ask? please be specific about what you want to ask. your question is too broad.. you can use http://www.asp.net/identity. There is 2-3 days learning curve. once you are over you can implement it anywhere. it can do most of the things that are required

Answer (score 0):

It is always easier to implement your own registration table for username and password. Use your database, make table for username, password etc...Try using session variables...just it. Have a nice day.